# Azure autoML weight columns

Tags: azure, machine-learning, multiclass-classification, weighted, automl

I am using autoML for training purposes, however my dataset is very imbalanced.
It is a multiclass task with 5 classes and I want to minimize this effect when training.
I have verified the documentation and it seems autoML support the creation of a new column with weights.

My doubts are: What is the range I am supposed to use? At this moment I am using 30, 40, 1.5 and 4 (I imagine weight should be used as multiplier). Can I use them?
About new dataset, I know this column will not exist anymore, so how can the model understand that?

Length of each class:

A: 12730
B: 181733
C: 623848
D: 1056696
E: 18210